# EU4 Where does AE got from colonial region with European power affect?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

So if I take Holland's provinces in Cuba will that increase my AE with neighboring countries in the colonial region or in Europe. In other words is distance calculated from the point of view of the province taken or the country?

Answer (score 1):

I have no means to check now, so my answer is an educated guess at best. Countries which are interested in what happens in the Caribbean region will get AE against you. In this case, Holland and neighboring countries/colonial nations (especially if they share the same religion as the provinces you took). The further they are, the less AE they'll get (La Plata, for instance, will most probably close to none, if none at all).

I would not expect any European countries to get any AE. In any case, in the peace deal window, you can see how much AE your deal will generate, and in the cases where a coalition could form after the deal is sealed, you should see with which country(ies) you will get AE, and how much, if those country(ies) might be part of the coalition.